# Get all content from bootstrap #editor div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, editor

After my using Bootstrap editable div I have some like this:

```
<span>
  Simple text
  <u>Hello!</u>
  Second text.  
</span>
```

All what I need - get all text from div, but if I use this recursive function, its return only content from elements, but text "Simple text" and "Second text" stay away from this function.

```
function parseElem(e){
  var r='';
  if(e.children('*').size()>0){
    e.children('*').each(function(){        
        r+=parseElem($(this));
    });
    return r;
  } else {
    return e.html().replace('<br>','\n');
  }    
}
```

And if I have

```
<span>
  He<b>ll</b>o!
  <p>
    <span>
      this
      <i>is</i>
      real
    </span>
    example  
  </p>
</span>
```

I want to leave tags i,u and stroke in returned value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should filter the contents of your span down to your requirements. Just add any tags you do not want unwrapped to the `:not()` selector.

```
$('span').find(':not(b, i, u)').contents().unwrap();
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot all aspects of my question. Now I update it. You answer is right, but it`s not all.

Comment: My DOM has more than one label of children. It has grand-children & grand-grand-children :)
And if I have `<i>Hi!</i>` I want to return `<i>Hi!</i>` - not only "Hi!".

Comment: Ahh, I see - my answer has been updated to reflect your new criteria.